# How to display custom facebook feed in my website using php like twitter

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have looked all over the website and didn't get anything.

What I'd like to do is, i have a facebook page, and i want to display latest post in my website footer page using php. i just want to display only `post description and time` from facebook in my formatted css. tweeter provide same facility but i am not sure about facebook. please help to configure it in my website

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the HybridAuth library.

> http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ 
>   http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html

After initializing Facebook Adapter, it's just a matter of querying the desired object with Facebook API

> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/